# Nuxt js/Babel `SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.`

Tags: cross-browser, babeljs, nuxt.js

I have a web application that I create on Nuxt.js, But I have noticed that there are compiling bugs in some of the browsers (Like Safari, IE), I think this is the fault of the Babel configuration, then i run `npm run build` ES6 is not compiled, and I have errors in my console
for cross-browsing testing, I am using Browserstack
I have following errors in the console:

`Unexpected token '...'. Expected a property name`

`SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.`

How can i configure Babel to compile ES6?

Comment: Which version are you targeting? Nuxt should compile it out of the box to ES5, especially if not using the `modern` flag. Btw, you can probably ditch IE since it's support will be over pretty soon by Microsoft itself.

Comment: Hi, After I tested my application in BrowserStack I found that problem only occurred in Safari versions (Safari 10, 9 and less), currently, these are not the versions that matter to me, but after research, I found this new plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxt/babel-preset-app, I think the manual configuration of  preset should solve this problem in Safari  older versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your code is not working on Safari v10 and below. Looking at some stats here:

- https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-partially-combined-market-share#monthly-202007-202107
- https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_safari.asp
- https://caniuse.com/?search=flex
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Safari_10_2

It looks like Safari is used with a minority of versions but those are mostly v13 and v14. Those are far more modern then then one you do not support.
Safari v10 is actually from 2007, so I can think that it's safe to say that you can ditch this version totally.

Even if Safari is not an evergreen browser (meaning `updating-itself` like Firefox or Chrome), people still using it are not on that old of a version.

You need to remember that if you want to support a version that old, you will heavily impact the overall performance of the whole website for every user. Okay, 0.5% of people will have a better experience (those stuck in 2007) but everybody else will need to carry the weight of that old babel-transpiled version.

You could make 2 bundles (one modern and for super old legacy browsers) and serve either one or the other depending if they do support ES modules. I cannot find the Google/HTTP 203 talking about this one.
But IMO, this is a lot of work (not that trivial) for a super tiny population, I'd rather pass on this and focus on more important things to handle.

Even a11y is reaching more people. Even tho, it's probably on a lower priority than Safari v10.
Here are my 2cts. If I find the video, I may update my answer.